# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address - error while communicating between 2 .net core web apps in localhost

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to docker and I have a visual studio solution with 2 dotnet core projects - UI and API. I've added docker support for both projects and they worked normally anytime I debug. Now they have an http client to call the api from the web and it suddenly starts giving the "Cannot assign requested address" error.

The weird thing here is that this error only comes up from just one PC. I have a second PC that still runs the projects smoothly. None of the other team members sees this error.

I've pruned all containers and images but that didn't help.
I'm not using docker-compose so the answers I found on related questions can't work for me.

The article [here](https://medium.com/it-dead-inside/docker-containers-and-localhost-cannot-assign-requested-address-6ac7bc0d042b) explains how localhost is being interpreted differently in docker but I'm not sure how to make his solution work for me.

The fact that this issue doesn't occur on other PCs is what really baffles me here.

Note: I'm not sure what part of the code I need to share because I don't know what's relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem when creating a client using the `localhost` url. I replaced `http://localhost:5001` with `http://host.docker.internal:5001` and it worked.

Comment: This solution worked for me; can you provide any detail or references on why this works?

Comment: It is related to how docker works. When starting project1 in docker it is mapped to some port on your localhost (like 5001), when starting project2 it is mapped to another port on your localhost. You can access both apps from your browser or CLI or visualstudio or any program because those programs are running on your localhost.
The problem appear when you want to connect from one app inside docker to another app inside docker, they do not see themselves under ports binded to localhost. What Dorin posted is a workaround that is accessing docker network directly, it will work only on windows.

Comment: What a nice solution- no more nned to map urls to localhost. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it sure is the simplest. Thanks! I like it simple!

Comment: I encountered the same issue on Linux. The thing is from within the docker container localhost refers to the container itself. So we have to use the host IP address instead of localhost. In my case it was 172.17.0.1.
Credits to: https://forums.docker.com/t/localhost-and-docker-compose-networking-issue/23100

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 4):

If you use docker-compose you can use the name of the service in your compose.yml as the host name, for example:

```
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  webapi1:
    ...
  eventmanager:
    ...
```

You can request your second container within the docker network as:

```
using var client = new RestClient("http://eventmanager");
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks much much better.